AuditD - Add group ID to USER_CHAUTHTOK event
I have some USER_CHAUTHTOK events in AuditD log like this
Dec  4 12:50:40 v-stand-05 audispd: node=10.10.0.1 type=USER_CHAUTHTOK msg=audit(1733305840.550:51890): pid=6965 uid=0 auid=1111 ses=1214 subj=unconfined msg='op=adding user to group acct="user" exe="/usr/sbin/usermod" hostname=host1 addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success' UID="root" AUID="user2"

I can see that user was added to the group, but there's no group ID or group name.
Could I config the AuditD rules or the message format to add any group information?
